# Ruby does not detect after installing using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

My configurations
Ubuntu 14.04 amd64
I followed [this tutorial](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) to install Ruby

1. Successfully installed ruby.
2. Closed the Terminal.
3. Checking

> ruby -v

shows

> ```
> The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
>  * ruby
>  * ruby1.8
> Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
> ```

4.Runs the command

> [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

from the tutorial and then check with ruby -v and it works !!( Shows the version )

5.I tried a many times by closing the terminal and typing ruby -v command every time it shows ruby is not installed and typed the same command from the tutorial then it detect the ruby.

How can avoid this ?

Comment: have u installed rvm ?

Comment: follow the instructions [here](http://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal) to configure rvm for your `gnome-terminal`

Comment: @sp1rs  Yes I installed rvm.  `rvm -v
rvm 1.25.22 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]`

Comment: @bjhaid I checked the [link](http://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal). It works..!!

Comment: @NairG I would post it as an answer you and can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions on making rvm work in gnome-terminal can be found [here](http://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal), quoting the instructions:

> For RVM to work properly, you have to set the 'Run command as login
>   shell' checkbox on the Title and Command tab inside of
>   gnome-terminal's Settings page